# Specifying the Telnet window size

Tags: linux, unix, telnet

I'm trying to use say a command on a remote system that I'm connected to. A command like "top" where it it uses the full screen to display output, but telnet seems to have a default window size. Does anybody know how to change it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to have a default window size"? It doesn't have a window, it runs in the terminal (which might of course be running in a window, but telnet can hardly resize that window).

Comment: Command line version of telnet? X version? Other?

Comment: it's the commandline version, what I mean is since an application like top or vim tends to use the whole terminal size ie 30 rows each say 100 characters long and it defaults to something smaller than that say 20 rows that are 50 characters long.

Comment: General comment: telnet is a horribly insecure protocol and should be avoided whenever possible (that is, *always* unless you're talking to some closed piece of hardware and even then only over a hardwired internal network). Use ssh instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I found out myself how to do it...

I needed to set the evioronment variables LINES and COLUMNS on the system that I was telneted too, it didn't really have anything to do with telnet itself. I did it in the following way:

I first ran "resize" to get the amount of lines and columns my current terminal was it gave me the following:

```
COLUMNS=157
LINES=53
export COLUMNS LINES
```

I then pasted this in to the system I was telneted to.

TADA! :)

Answer (score 4):

After you've telneted to the system you can set the terminal size with

```
stty rows 25 columns 80
```

No, telnet is likely not smart enough to somehow transfer these values to the destination system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [debugging steps outlined here](http://teaching.idallen.org/dat2330/04f/notes/telnet_usage.html)?